# R: Looping through list and passing values to API of UN Comtrade. + Programming a pause in the loop

Tags: r, api, loops

I want to pass the arguments of a list to a function calling the API of the UN Comtrade Data. Also, I need to add pauses after each query to the API to not exceed the restrictions of UN Comtrade.

Without the loop I call the API this way:

`q276a <- get.Comtrade(r="276", p="0", freq="M", ps="all", cc="842520", rg="2", fmt="csv")
df_q276a<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, q1a)`.

`r="276"` is specifying that I want the data from the Reporting Country with the code "276" which is Germany. To get data from all reporting countries I want to loop through a list with all the country codes. (I can't just specify "all" since the API restricts the value "all" for only one of the paramters r, p, ps)

What I've written so far is:

```
for (i in ls_reporters){
  assign(paste("q", i,"a", sep = ""), get.Comtrade(r="i", p="0", freq="M", ps="all", cc="842520", rg="2", fmt="csv"))
}
```

This produces the error

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

My code seems to pass `r="i"` to the API instead of cycling through the values in ls_reporters und passing these to the API, e.g. 4 then 18 and so on. However, if I type i I get "4" which is the first value of the ls_reporters.

As additional Question: How can i program a pause of a few seconds after each iteration to not exceed the 1 request per second restriction of UN Comtrade?

If there is a more elegant way programming this without loops I would be glad to learn it. I am pretty new to R.

The R code to query data through the public API can be found [here](http://comtrade.un.org/data/Doc/api/ex/r).
The documentation for the API can be found [here](http://comtrade.un.org/data/doc/api/)

Comment: Have a look at `paste0` and `parse(text = paste0(...))`. But I have in mind that the approach using `parse` is not fast.

Comment: To pass the query parameters as a list you could switch to `httr::GET` as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71854457/9841389).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `lapply` where you pass `i` as on object reference and not a literal with quotes (if `ls_reporters` holds numeric data, wrap `i` in `as.character()`). Also, use use `Sys.sleep(time)` to pause execution of script between iterations, `time` measured in seconds.

Do note, the returned output unlike a `for` loop is a large list of data elements equal to the number of elements in `ls_reporters`. Should you need individual objects for each country data, use `list2env()` (but no need to flood environment with potentially 100s of objects if not needed):

```
# LIST OF COMTRADE DATA (LENGTH EQUAL TO INPUT LIST)
comtrade_data <- lapply(ls_reporters, function(i) {
                            Sys.sleep(1)
                            tmp <- get.Comtrade(r=i, p="0", freq="M", ps="all", 
                                                cc="842520", rg="2", fmt="csv")
                            df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, tmp))
                            return(df)
                 })

# NAME EACH ELEMNT OF NEW LIST BY PREFIXING "q"
comtrade_data <- setNames(comtrade_data, paste0("df_q", ls_reporters))

# CREATE df_q1, df_q2, df_q3, ... AS INDIVIDUAL OBJECTS
list2env(comtrade_data, envir=.GlobalEnv)

# EVEN ROW BIND TO DATAFRAME (IF ELEMENTS HAVE SAME EXACT ONE-LEVEL DATA STRUCTURE)
df <- do.call(rbind, comtrade_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Your code helped me to understand lapply better!
One more question: I assume that row binding to one dataframe does only work if all of the elements of the list have the same dimensions (is that what you meant with "one-level data structure")? For the whole comtrade_data it doesn't work for me. The command only produces a dataframe with 2 columns. However, for each individual object I get a nice dataframe with, e.g., `df_q156a <-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, q156a))`

Comment: Great! As I cannot see the comtrade output, I cannot tell. But yes, in order to use `do.call(rbind, list)`, elements need to be same structure and name. If at least one differs, call won't work. Of course you can even `lapply()` to produce individual frames!

Comment: I'm still so bad with R and apply that I can't get individual frames from the list. I tried sth. along the line `paste0("df_q", ls_reporters1,"a") <-lapply(comtrade_data, function(i){ as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,comtrade_data[[i]])
})`
I know that assigning names with `df_name<- lapply()` doesn't work (still loop thinking) but I don't know how to name the dataframes in lapply. Also the right-hand side doesn't work either. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to get all the elements of the list into a big dataframe so I can run analysis or export to dta and use in STATA.

Comment: Got it. Of course, you can use R for analysis. But export such dataframe to csv and import into Stata with `insheet` command. Before R, I only knew and used Stata (now I can't go back)! Cheers!

Comment: Still I can't use apply to extract the individual data frames if the elments of the list comtrade_data have different dimensions. This is what I am doing to do it one by one `df_q792 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, comtrade_data$q792))`. How could I automate this with apply?
Also see my comment from _30th Aug, 15:17_.
THANKS!

Comment: No need for second `lapply()`. See updated adding `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, ...))` to first `lapply()`. Be sure to then run `setNames()` and `list2env()` as these two together create individual dfs. Also, reconsider retaining all those dfs in memory. Just use its list container for referencing and assigning (after `setNames`): `comtrade_data$q792` would be the q792 df.